# Regex matching numbers without letters in front of it

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match numbers like "100", "1.1", "5.404", IF they do not include a letter in front like this: "V102".

Here is my current regular expression:

```
(?<![A-Za-z])[0-9.]+
```

This is supposed to match any character 0-9. one or more repetitions, if prefix is absent (A-Za-z).

But what it does is match V102, as 02, so it just chips away V and one more letter and then the rest fits while it actually shouldn't match that case at all. How can I make it so it grabs all numbers, and then checks if the prefix is non existent?

Comment: Do you actually mean to match _inputs_ or tokens within an input? The answer is highly dependent on that. For instance, in `A 922`, do you mean to match `922` or nothing?

Comment: Match tokens within an input I guess. It can be a long string of random stuff, and it should match all numbers that does not include a letter in front of it.

Comment: @Barmar I did thanks, but thats not how I have it in c#. I just added it to escape formatting, for whatever reason (? is the start of some Stackoverflow command. But then I guess its not needed after I put it in a code box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add digits and decimal point to your negative lookbehind:

```
(?<![A-Za-z0-9.])[0-9.]+
```

This will force all matches to start with a non-digit and non-letter (i.e., a space or other separator).  That way the end of a number will not be a valid match either.

Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/EDuI2D9jnW

Answer (score 3):

could you possibly be able to use word boundaries?

```
\b[0-9\.]+\b
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the regex:

```
(?<![A-Za-z0-9])[0-9.]+
```

Comment: This works thanks, mellamokb submitted almost the exact same thing a few seconds before. So I'll chose him.

Comment: You need decimal point in your negative lookbehind as well, otherwise it will incorrectly match `.00` in `F1.00` (example: http://www.rubular.com/r/jGdtWa5k2a)

Comment: @mellamokb Good point, missed that. You've got it in the answer that will be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want letters or spaces anywhere in your string, then this should work:

```
^[0-9.]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

**A Non-Regex solution.**

If you have the following string, then you can use `double.TryParse` to see if the string is a double. Try:

```
string str = "100 1.1 V100 d333 ABC 1.1";
double temp;
string[] result = str.Split().Where(r => (double.TryParse(r, out temp))).ToArray();
```

Or if you need a double array in return then:

```
double[] numberArray = str.Split()
                          .Where(r => double.TryParse(r, out temp))
                          .Select(r => double.Parse(r))
                          .ToArray();
```

Comment: He only said to reject numbers with a letter prefix. This solution will reject numbers with any non-numeric prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the caret `^` operator. This operator indicates that you want your pattern to start at the beginning of the input. For example `^[0-9.]+` will match inputs that begin with a digit or a `.` and has any number of them.
Note that this pattern does not match only numbers, as it matches also patterns with more then 1 dot, for example `2.00.2`, which is not a valid number.